# the generated excel doesn't start from first row if there are multiple if

Tags: java, jxls

I am using `jxls 2.14.0`, I have an excel template which looks like following:

```
A1            A2            A3     -> row1
${b.a1}     ${b.a2}     ${b.a3}    -> row2
B1            B2            B3     -> row3
${b.b1}     ${b.b2}     ${b.b3}    -> row4
C1            C2           C3      -> row5
${b.c1}     ${b.c2}     ${b.c3}    -> row6
```

it has three parts : A, B and C, each time only one part will be generated.

for cell `A1`, I added:

```
jx:area(lastCell="C6")
jx:if(condition="type == 1", lastCell="C2" )
```

for cell `${b.a1}`, I add `jx:each(items="list" var="b" lastCell="C2")`

for cell `B1`, I add `jx:if(condition="type == 2", lastCell="C4" )`,
for cell `${b.b1}`, I add `jx:each(items="list" var="b" lastCell="C4")`

for cell `C1`, I add `jx:if(condition="type == 3", lastCell="C6" )`,
for cell `${b.c1}`, I add `jx:each(items="list" var="b" lastCell="C6")`

if `type == 1`, then only part A will be generated and it starts from first row;

if `type == 2`, then only part B will be generated and it start from first row too.

but for part C, it starts from third row, first row and second row are empty row, why? how to make part C also start from first row?